# Unable to get custom headers using imap

Tags: node.js, node-imap

I am able to send a email with custom headers using Nodemailer module. But I am unable to get these custom headers when I retrieve email using node Imap module

I tried usign mailparser module but still I am unable to see custom headers. If I open the email details in outlook client , i see my custom headers.

```
 Stream is coming from 'body' call back.               
               simpleParser(stream)
                .then(mail => {
                    //console.log(mail.headers);
                    console.log(inspect(mail, false, 22));
                })
```

Has any one tried to access custom headers ?

Answer (score 0):

issue was with Office 365 mail server. I am able to get custom headers when I run the same code against gmail